# Converting 2D array image to table using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, table, image, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, array

I'm trying to get a table from a 2d-array image. Basically, the Image (called `segmentationInfo`) looks like this:

```
The 2-D ‘LandTrendr’ annual segmentation array looks like this:

[
  [1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, ...] // Year list 
  [ 811,  809,  821,  813,  836,  834,  833,  818,  826,  820,  765,  827,  775, ...] // Source list
  [ 827,  825,  823,  821,  819,  817,  814,  812,  810,  808,  806,  804,  802, ...] // Fitted list
  [   1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1, ...] // Is Vertex list
]
```

How do I convert this to an *exportable* table?

My commented code is below.

```js
// START INPUTS

var area = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-64.77293019260956, -2.4770762036671767],
          [-64.77293019260956, -2.5250956006529575],
          [-64.71902852024628, -2.5250956006529575],
          [-64.71902852024628, -2.4770762036671767]]], null, false);

// define collection parameters
var startYear = 1986;
var endYear = 2020;
var startDay = '06-01';
var endDay = '12-31';
var index = 'B5';
var maskThese = ['cloud', 'shadow', 'water'];

// define landtrendr parameters
var runParams = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.6,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true, 
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};

// define change parameters
var changeParams = {
  delta:  'loss',
  sort:   'greatest', //option: newtest, least, oldest, fastest, slowest
  year:   {checked:true, start:1986, end:2020},
  mag:    {checked:true, value:200,  operator:'>'}, //default 200
  dur:    {checked:true, value:4,    operator:'<'}, // default 4
  preval: {checked:true, value:300,  operator:'>'},
  mmu:    {checked:true, value:11},
  
};

// END INPUTS


// load the LandTrendr.js module
var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js'); 

// add index to changeParams object
changeParams.index = index;

// run landtrendr
var lt = ltgee.runLT(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, area, index, [], runParams, maskThese);

print(lt, 'LandTrendr');

// selecting the LandTrendr band

var segmentationInfo = lt.select(['LandTrendr']); // subset the LandTrendr segmentation info
print(segmentationInfo, 'segmentInfo'); //It contains 4 rows and as many columns as there are annual observations for a given pixel through the time series.
```

Answer (score 3):

Table export lets you export multidimensional arrays, so you just need to convert things into a collection of features.

If you *really* only have the 1 array, then it'd be something like this:

```
Export.table.toDrive(
    ee.FeatureCollection([
        ee.Feature(null, {segmentationInfo: segmentationInfo})
    ]))
```

But LandTrendr produces those arrays on a per-pixel basis and in your code, segmentInfo is an image, so you probably want to export a region of the image.  You can do that with reduceRegion and a toCollection reducer to produce a table of pixel values (specify a scale smaller than 1000 if you want smaller pixels):

```
var table = segmentationInfo.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.toCollection(["LandTrendr"]), area, 1000).get("LandTrendr")
```

If you want to split the arrays into 4 separate lists, then you can either map a function over the table to produce 4 values instead of 1 (or you could just split the input image into 4 bands before you run the reduceRegion).

```
table = ee.FeatureCollection(table).map(function(f) {
    var arr = ee.Array(f.get('LandTrendr'))
    return ee.Feature(null, {
        year: arr.cut([0, -1]),
        source: arr.cut([1, -1]),
        fitted: arr.cut([2, -1]),
        vertex: arr.cut([3, -1])
    })
})
```

All that said, because its computed on a per-pixel basis, and there are usually a lot of pixels, most people don't export the whole results of LandTrendr.  More often you make a visualization of first/last/largest/count-of disturbance, and export that as an image.